# How to customize the Chrome prompts using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, geolocation, alert

I have to customize the chrome prompts with the theme that matches the CSS of my website. I need the location access for users, so have to customize the below prompt similar to my website theme.
Is it possible to customize the default prompts ?
Can please anybody help me out?

[image]

Comment: Nope, otherwise you could change "wants to ... know your location" to "wants to ... entertain you", which would be a security issue

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you could change the appearance of dialogs prompting the user to grant you security rights then it would be much easier to mislead the user about their purpose.

Consequently, this is not possible.